# Is there any tool to empower code-reviews in Visual-Studio?

Tags: .net, visual-studio

Are you aware of any tool that I can add-in to Visual studio and create some notes, etc on a separate place without a need to check out the code while I do a code review and re-play it later to walk through the review?

For example I will walk through a method call chain and put some notes on some lines without really editing the code. But later on this tool would help me to see what notes I have taken on the code.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1071424/code-annotation-tool-for-visual-studio?rq=1

Comment: Why the requirement to stay within visual studio? Seems quite arbitrary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For VS 2012:**

[Code Review feature in Visual Studio 2012](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mvpawardprogram/archive/2012/09/04/new-code-review-feature-in-visual-studio-2012.aspx): 
For the first time, Visual Studio 2012 includes a Code Review process out of the box.

[Visual Studio Premium and Ultimate 2012: Using Code Review to Improve Quality](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Visual-Studio-2012-Premium-and-Ultimate-Overview/Visual-Studio-Ultimate-2012-Using-Code-Review-to-Improve-Quality)

For **other VS version** you can check out these tools:

1) [Review Assistant — Code Review Tool](http://www.devart.com/review-assistant/):

Lightweight peer code review tool, add-in for Visual Studio

Automated code inspection handled by code review tools helps to improve coding quality, hone developers' skills, and ship software with less defects.

2) [StickyNotes][4]:

It is a Visual Studio plug in that seamlessly integrates with the IDE providing sticky notes capabilities to documents within a solution. While several methods exist for lightweight code review, such as "over the shoulder" reviews, review by email and meetings, the most effective reviews are conducted by tools to facilitate the process. (Edit: URL no longer works)

Comment: VS 2012 rocks. Theyre TFS power tools made all the pain of adoption worth it!

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Visual Studio
2. Choose Tools...Options...
3. Select the Environment (tab) on the left
4. Select the Task List sub-item
5. Here (on the right) You can create task list items.
6. Create one called CREV. (code review)
7. Now you can go through the code and add #CREV tags and comments.
8. They will appear in your Messages.

Later, when you do the code review, the Task List items will show up in your "Messages" window.  You can double-click those and they will take you directly to the spot in the code you want to talk about.  You can delete the comments as you cover them, or the owner can remove as your code review suggestions are taken into account.

Later you can do a Search/Replace for those lines and remove them fairly easily.
Comments do not affect the code at all.  They are not compiled.

Free and easy.
**This is a fantastic idea and I'm sure it will be upvoted heavily so don't miss out.**

Comment: But this still requires to add the reviews directly on the code which requires the file to be checked-out. (I like the idea though)

Comment: You are right.  It is a bit problematic, since you are changing the source files.  In Subversion you could do an Export which is a get( in other version control systems) which creates a copy of the code which isn't checked out and then make the changes.  But, of course there are problems there too.  Good luck.